# Every element of list has same element outside function.

Tags: java, list, arraylist, null

```
 svm_node n=new svm_node();
for (String tk:instance.keySet()){
            System.out.println(tk + " "+ instance.get(tk));
            if(IndexDic.containsKey(tk)){

            n.index=(IndexDic.get(tk));
            n.value=instance.get(tk);
            nodes.add(n);
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("does not contain"+tk);
        }
        }
```

I have the above code. After I output the nodes value on to console or check using debugger all elements have same value. That is, all n in nodes have same values. What can I do to deal with hat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding the same `svm_node` object to the collection over and over again.  To fix this, move the instantiation of the `svm_node` to inside the loop:

```
for (String tk:instance.keySet()) {
    svm_node n=new svm_node();
    System.out.println(tk + " "+ instance.get(tk));

    if (IndexDic.containsKey(tk)) {
        n.index = (IndexDic.get(tk));
        n.value = instance.get(tk);
        nodes.add(n);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("does not contain"+tk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed that!

Comment: But for (svm_node node:nodes)
      {
       if(node!=null)
       {
        p.x[i][u]=new svm_node();
        p.x[i][u]=node;
       u=u+1;}
      }

Answer (score 0):

You should call `svm_node n = new svm_node()` inside the for-Loop. Otherwise, the same Node will be overwritten!